# How to get AS two separate selectors with UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql

As sadly SQL is my weakest skill.

I'm trying to use `UNION` in a `VIEW`, where I can get statistics from two different tables with one query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `customer_count` FROM `Customers`
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `supplier_count` FROM `Suppliers`;
```

<sup>**[[Demo table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union)]**</sup>

However, it only returns **customer_count**, with two rows. Is there anyway, to make this work, so it returns **customer_count** and **supplier_count** separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a `cross join` to see the results adjacent to each other in one row. So you would `select` from both the tables without a `join` condition.

```
select * from
(select count(*) as customer_count from Customers) x,
(select count(*) as supplier_count from Suppliers) y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers) as customer_count,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Suppliers) AS supplier_count
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was one of my first thoughts as well, but sadly it doesn't work in phpmyadmin, giving the line 3 as error and it doesn't working in the Demo table. What could be wrong?

Comment: Sure it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/061d6b/1. You should really avoid w3schools. That does not work so well

Comment: Btw I just try it on w3schools and works ok . http://i.stack.imgur.com/kqiCt.png. The difference is if you want each total in separated column or each total in a different row.

Comment: don't why OP doesnt select this as an aswer becasue you answer first, so i give you a +1

Comment: the OP mentioned it wasn't working in `phpmyadmin`. not in `w3schools`

Answer (score 1):

Using your Table Demo.

The key is use alias so the field names match on each union select.

In this case `TableSource` and `Total`

```
SELECT 'Customer' as TableSource, Count(City) as Total FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT 'Suppliers' as TableSource, Count(City) as Total FROM Suppliers;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE  VIEW `vw_count` AS 
select (select count(0) from `tbl`) AS   `customer_count`,
       (select count(0) from `tbl2`) AS `supplier_count`;
```